# Boto3 get current deployed Elastic Beanstalk version?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Anybody knows how to retrieve the currently running Elastic Beanstalk version using the [SDK](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elasticbeanstalk.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the ARN to `describe_platform_version()` https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elasticbeanstalk.html#ElasticBeanstalk.Client.describe_platform_version

Comment: Maybe my question was not precise. I want the application version currently running. Not the "platform" version.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, that will depend on the language and framework you are using, and you won't be able to get it via the SDK. You'll have to do something like `process.env.npm_package_version` for nodejs or `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version` for .NET.

Comment: You could use resource tags to store the version and make it retrievable via the SDK https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.tagging.html

Comment: I now store the information in S3 during deployment .. not nice but works.